# custom flutter api in flutter waving hand

Tags: flutter

Hi below code how to use the below icon in my project.I tried to added giving an error.

Can any one help on this issue The getter 'waving_hand' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'.  Try importing the library that defines 'waving_hand', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'waving_hand'.

```
Icon(
  Icons.waving_hand,
),
```

Comment: There is no `Icons.waving_hand` provided with the flutter's material icons. Where did you see that icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per flutter documentation for Icon Class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html), the `Icons.waving_hand` are not available in the material package you can used instead of another icons

You can used Icon widget like below:

```
Icon(
  Icons.add,
)
```

Your result screen using Icon widget -> [image]

Or you can used flutter unicode emoji also [here](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/1.0/emoji-data.txt) like below

```
Text(
    '\u270B ',
)
```

Your result screen using unicode emoji -> [image]